# MotoGP 2017 events to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, import

The 2017 Calendar of MotoGP™ is [published on the web](http://www.motogp.com/en/news/2016/12/07/2017-motogp-calendar-updated/211047). Is there any way to import MotoGP 2017 events to my Google Calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a calendar (displayed as a table on a webpage) can be imported in Google Calendar, though not without a little headache. My strategy is to use  `importhtml` to import it in a spreadsheet, then save as CSV file, and import it into calendar.

**Step 1**: Make sure the Locale setting of your Google spreadsheet is consistent with the date format used on the webpage you are importing. For example, I normally have United States as the locale (with date format mm/dd)  but the MotoGP calendar uses dd/mm, so I changed my locale to Germany for this experiment.

**Step 2**: import the calendar with

```
=importthml("http://www.motogp.com/en/news/2016/12/07/2017-motogp-calendar-updated/211047"; "table"; 1)
```

Let's say this formula is in A1 of Sheet1. The semicolons are used as separators because of European locale. The dates should be recognized as dates except since they don't have a year, the year will be assumed to be the current one. If you are doing this in 2016 for 2017 calendar... this will be need to be fixed on the next step.

**Step 3**: Create another sheet, with the top row headers "Subject" and "Start Date" as [Google instructs](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en). Under the first header, put `={Sheet1!C2:C19}` to get the event names. Under the second, put `=arrayformula(text(Sheet1!B2:B19+365; "yyyy-mm-dd"))` which adds 365 to each event date*, moving it from 2016 to 2017, and then formats it in the [internationally accepted way](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

**Step 4**: Save the sheet with these two columns as a CSV file. Then follow the [instructions](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118?hl=en) om importing events: "Settings > Calendars > Import Calendar".

---

(*) Why 365, when 2016 is a leap year? Because all of the events happen in March or later... bullet dodged. Dates are fun.